# Sorting blocks of a file in unix

Tags: sort

I have file like.

```
HR|testing file
BH|100
B2|cat|10
B2|dog|20
BT|4
BH|105
B2|apple|10
B2|banana|20
B2|melon|10
BT|5
BH|102
B2|fan|10
B2|bulb|20
B2|washer|10
B2|dryer|10
BT|6
TR|17
```

I need to sort the blocks based on 2nd field in BH record of each block. The rows in the blocks should remain intact. For the above file, the expected output is:

```
HR|testing file
**BH|100**
B2|cat|10
B2|dog|20
BT|4
**BH|102**
B2|fan|10
B2|bulb|20
B2|washer|10
B2|dryer|10
BT|6
**BH|105**
B2|apple|10
B2|banana|20
B2|melon|10
BT|5
TR|17
```

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? (What did work?) Where did the `**` marks come from in the output? Are we supposed to add those?

Answer (score 3):

This should work and sorts each block based on `#` in `BH|#` as block header line and in ascending `BH|100`, `BH|102`, `BH|105`, `...` order.

```
awk -v RS='BH|TR' 'NR>1{ seen[NR]=$0; next } { printf $0 }
   END{ TR="TR"seen[NR]; delete seen[NR]; asort(seen);  
        for(x in seen) printf "BH"seen[x]; printf TR }' infile
```

```
HR|testing file
BH|100
B2|cat|10
B2|dog|20
BT|4
BH|102
B2|fan|10
B2|bulb|20
B2|washer|10
B2|dryer|10
BT|6
BH|105
B2|apple|10
B2|banana|20
B2|melon|10
BT|5
TR|17
```

- This `RS='BH|TR'` defines both `BH` and `TR` as record separators (default is `\n`ewline).
- This block `NR>1{ seen[NR]=$0; next }` will run for all **R**ecords but first (`NR` is **N**umber of **R**ecord); so for each Record Number as the key (Index) of an associated array called *seen* the value of the whole record will be set to it and then read `next` record.
- If it's not first Record, then *`{ printf $0 }`* it. This will run only once, because next time `NR>1`.

At the end the block `END{ ... }` will be run and do:

- This `TR="TR"seen[NR]` copying the last Record from the array inserted into a variable called *TR* and then delete it from the array `delete seen[NR]`.
- This `asort(seen)` sorts the array *seen* based on their values saved; then
- We loop `for(x in seen)` over this array and `printf "BH"seen[x]`
- At the end we print the copied *TR*.

---

If you don't mind the first and last lines in your file, you could do also:

```
sed '1d; $d' infile |awk '{printf $0(/^BT/?"\n":"#")}' |sort |tr '#' '\n'
```

Answer (score -2):

I found a quick and easy way to do it. Please suggest if there is a better way to do it.

Removed header and trailer records.
combined and put in a # as a line separator between the lines in a block into one line.
Sorted by specific field
Replaced the # with new line

```
gawk '/^HC/ && line {print line; line=""} {line = line ? line"#"$0 : $0} END {print line}' input.txt | sort -t"|" -nk 13 | tr '#' '\n' > finaloutput.txt
```

Comment: there is no `HC` in your given sample data nor the commands is storing